# How I can use TS Generics for react-hook-form interfaces?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-hook-form

This is my code:

```
export interface PatientFormInputs {
  patientId: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  day: string;
  month: string;
  year: string;
}

In react component: 

const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    reset,
    // formState: { isValid },
  } = useForm<PatientFormInputs>({
    defaultValues: {
      month: '',
    },
  });

 return (
   <PatientInfo
        register={register}
        initialData={initialData}
        selectedMonth={selectedMonth}
        setSelectedMonth={setSelectedMonth}
      />
 )
```

And on this way I added interface in PatientInfo:

```
interface PatientInfoProps {
  register: UseFormRegister<PatientFormInputs>;
  initialData?: PatientBE;
  selectedMonth: string | null;
  setSelectedMonth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | null>>;
}

export const PatientInfo: FC<PatientInfoProps> = ({
  register,
  initialData,
  selectedMonth,
  setSelectedMonth,
}) => {...}
```

But I want to use Generics for register like this: `register: UseFormRegister<T>` on some places I need little different data so I want to have flexibility with Generics.

How to do that (I tried some ways but always facing with issues and errors)?

I tried something like this:

```
interface PatientInfoProps<T> {
  register: UseFormRegister<T>;
...
}
```

Also tried similar things also but nothing is good.

I expect to be able to use Generics for register type without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use generics for the `UseFormRegister` type in your `PatientInfoProps` interface, you can define the generic type for your `PatientInfoProps` and then use that generic type in the `register` property.

```
import { FC, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { UseFormRegister } from 'react-hook-form';

// Define a generic type for PatientInfoProps
interface PatientInfoProps<T> {
  register: UseFormRegister<T>;
  initialData?: PatientBE; // Assuming PatientBE is defined elsewhere
  selectedMonth: string | null;
  setSelectedMonth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | null>>;
}

Use the generic type in the PatientInfo component
export const PatientInfo: FC<PatientInfoProps<PatientFormInputs>> = ({
  register,
  initialData,
  selectedMonth,
  setSelectedMonth,
}) => {
  // Your component logic here
};
```

In the example above, `PatientInfoProps` is a generic interface that takes a type parameter `T`. The `register` property is then typed with `UseFormRegister<T>`. When using the `PatientInfo` component, you can specify the desired type for `T`, for example, `PatientFormInputs` in your case.

Make sure that `PatientFormInputs` is defined before you use it in the `PatientInfoProps`. If it's defined in the same file, ensure that it appears before the `PatientInfoProps` interface.

This approach should provide the flexibility you need with generics for the `register` type in your React component.

Comment: Thank you. 
Just one thing missing here, because vs code throw an error for <T> in UseFormRegister<T>. 
It requires FieldValues from react-hook-form so that need to add above like this: 
interface PatientInfoProps<T extends FieldValues> {
  register: UseFormRegister<T>;
  ...
}

Comment: Yes, right. I have just provided a solution without testing it actually as  I just wanted to provide you an overview of how this can be done. I will update the answer.